# Keras Resnet-50 image classification overfitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Hello I am getting overfitting with resnet-50 pretrained weights. I am trying to train RGB images of files and the dataset I am using comes with training and validation sets. I have 26 classes and about 14k images, 9 k training and 5k testing.

The name of data set is [maleviz](https://web.cs.hacettepe.edu.tr/%7Eselman/malevis/)

My validation accuracy is very low and my training accuracy reaches 1.000. My validation doesn't go over 0.50-0.55 so seems to be overfitting I think.. Is there something wrong with data like per class samples or is there something wrong with my model?

I expect resnet to perform well on this...

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping,ModelCheckpoint
from keras.layers import Input, Add, Dense, Activation, ZeroPadding2D, BatchNormalization,Flatten, Conv2D, AveragePooling2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D,MaxPool2D
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from keras.applications.resnet import ResNet50
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

samples = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(directory='malevis_train_val_300x300/train', target_size=(300,300))
imgs, labels = next(samples)
print(imgs.shape, labels.shape)
samples2 = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(directory='malevis_train_val_300x300/val', target_size=(300,300))
imgs2, labels2 = next(samples2)

classes = samples.class_indices.keys()
y = (sum(labels)/labels.shape[0])*100
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.bar(classes,y)
plt.show()

X_train, y_train = imgs,labels
X_val, y_val = imgs2,labels2
def define_model():
    model = ResNet50(weights = 'imagenet', pooling = 'avg', include_top = False, input_shape =(300,300,3))
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    flat1 = Flatten()(model.layers[-1].output)
    class1 = Dense(256,activation='relu',)(flat1)
    output = Dense(26,activation='softmax')(class1)
    model = Model(inputs = model.inputs, outputs=output)
    opt = Adam(lr =0.001)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = define_model()
model.summary()

history1 = model.fit(X_train,y_train, validation_data=(X_val,y_val), epochs = 200,batch_size = 20, steps_per_epoch = 4,shuffle=True)
scores = model.evaluate(X_val,y_val)
print('Final accuracy:', scores[1])

acc = history1.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history1.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history1.history['loss']
val_loss = history1.history['val_loss']

epochs = range(len(acc))

plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'r', label='Training accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'b', label='Validation accuracy')
plt.title('Training and validation accuracy')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.figure()


plt.show()
```

I have tried different optimizers, loss functions, target size, and added epochs per step.. Nothing really makes much different it still overfits. I am using softmax activation and freezing the layers and removing top. I just then add dense layer and output layer for 26 classes.I have tried with shuffling true and false

Comment: Can you provide the loss curve? It might help solving the issue. A general rule on helping overfitting would be to add a Dropout layer somewhere in the network.

Comment: @Michael thansk for the dropout layer suggestion. I will provide the loss curve as soon as I'll be able to.

Comment: I would suggest not to freeze all the layers of the pretrained ResNet. This would minimize the learning capability of the NN, as most trainable variables are frozen i.e. constant. You could unfreeze some of the initial convolutional layers as it would help them capture local features which might be specific to your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you a few things, one of them might be helpful:

1. You didn't provide any `classes` parameter inside `flow_from_directory()` make sure you have the proper folder structure as the documentation requires: [flow_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory)
2. Try changing the loss from `categorical_crossentropy` to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` if your output labels are **not** one-hot encoded. Ref: [Probabilistic losses | SparseCategoricalCrossentropy](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-class)